# How to compare two lists in python that prints out removed and added elements

Tags: python, list

I am currently having an issue of comparing two strings list in python. Currently, I have two lists called `list1` and `list2`.

Use Case 1: When `list1 = ['Entry', '280']` and `list2 = ['Entry', '240']`, I am able to get an output that I want which prints out `Added: 280`.

Use Case 2: And when `list1 = ['Entry', '280']` and `list2 =[]`, I get an output of `Removed: Entry 280`.

Use Case 3: Now the issue that I am currently having is when `list1= ['one', 'two']` and `list2 = ['three','four','five']`because with the current code I have below, I can't seem to figure out a way to produce an output of `Removed: one two; Added: three four five`?

Code for Use case 1:

```
list1 = ['Entry', '280']
list2 = ['Entry', '240']
diff_added = []
for element in list1:
   if element not in list2:
      diff_added.append(element)
str_diff = ' '.join(diff_added)
print(f'Added: {str_diff}')
```

Code for Use Case 2:

```
list1 = ['Entry', '280']
list2 = []
diff_removed = []
for element in list1:
   if element not in list2:
      diff_removed.append(element)
str_diff = ' '.join(diff_removed)
print(f'Removed: {str_diff}')
```

Comment: I would use [`set`s](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set) for this.  e.g. `added = set(list2) - set(list1); removed = set(list1) - set(list2)`

Comment: According to the desired output of your second and third use-cases, shouldn't the desired output of the first use-case be `Removed: 280; Added: 240`?

Comment: The `difflib` built-in module may be useful here.

Comment: Hi @PaulM. . Yes that is what I would want, but I could not figure out an optimal solution to get that output using the current code I have

Answer (score -1):

```
list1= ['one', 'two']
list2 = ['three','four','five']

diff_removed = []
diff_added = []
for element in list1:
   if element not in list2:
      diff_removed.append(element)
del element
str_diff1 = ' '.join(diff_removed)

for element in list2:
   if element not in list1:
      diff_added.append(element)
str_diff2 = ' '.join(diff_added)

print(f'Removed: {str_diff1}',f'Added:{str_diff2}')
```